# Outlook VSTO is it possible to use the address book control?

Tags: outlook, vsto

I need to mimic the adress book control in an Outlook VSTO project. It would be much simpler to use the real control, isn't it?

So, do you know a way to expose the address book control, and get what's selected within, of course?

Edit: Never mind, re-creating a basic version of the control will be way easyer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: third party [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) library offer this feature.

> RedemptionLoader.RDOSession.AddressBook.ShowAddressBook(...)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a third party addin.  you can do it with this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868361.aspx

this code below is in VBA but you can easily convert it to C#:

```
Sub SelectRecipients() 
Dim oMsg As MailItem 
Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
Dim oDialog As SelectNamesDialog 
Set oDialog = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog 
With oDialog 
.InitialAddressList = _ 
Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList 
.Recipients = oMsg.Recipients 
 If .Display Then 
 'Recipients Resolved 
 oMsg.Subject = "Hello" 
 oMsg.Send 
 End If 
 End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: indeed, but I had to be Outlook 2003 compliant by the time, and Redemption saved our lives on many occasions on this projects, worth every cent we spent on it.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Outlook does not let you specify the parent window handle when displaying the address book, so the main Outlook window will come on top of your window. Redemption lets you pass the parent window handle when calling ShowAddressBook.

Comment: As per Dmitry's commment, I ran into th parent window issue which kind of stinks so redemption is definately a better play because of that.  I am running into other issues trying to get Redemption to work (as per my comments on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423081/in-my-vsto-outlook-app-why-does-calling-selectnamesdialog-display-moves-my-fo/15423383?noredirect=1#comment21814413_15423383